# Can't save something written in the Serial Monitor for Arudino as a String/char

Tags: c++, string, char, arduino

When I type the word in for the first line, the first letter is saved for the second line and nothing is saved for the first line. How do I fix this problem?

Here's the code: http://pastebin.com/sXLjAvns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually figured this out with a friend. Here is the new source: `http://pastebin.com/GDxJwXxd`

I fixed it with a `for` loop that repeatedly saves the next character and saves it to the string. Then it uses another `for` loop and prints out each character of the string.

Answer (score 1):

Serial.read() only returns a single character, so the following:

```
while (Serial.available() == 0);
firstLine[16] = Serial.read();
Serial.println(firstLine);
```

Needs to be change to something similar to:

```
#define LEN   16
#define CR    13

int i=0;
char incoming;

while ((incoming!= CR) & (i<LEN-1))
{
   if (Serial.available())
   {
       incoming = Serial.read();
       firstline[i]=incoming;
       i++;
   }
}
firstline[i]=0;
Serial.println(firstLine);
```